# VCS for personal (one machine use)

Tags: version-control

Can anyone point me to a set of clear instructions of how to set up a VCS software. I am going to use it on my machine - so server and client on one machine.

I tried GIT that was recommended in various questions but its GUI was cumbersome and didn't make any sense to at all - I don't really have the time to delve into it either. I just need a SIMPLE VCS that will allow me to:

check in AND check out AND view history AND revert between versions

I also need it to be easy to set up, ideally it should be able to work out of the box.

Comment: Noooh! Don't even think of it! Use Mercurial or SVN, both of which have excellent GUIs. Really, CVS is at the end of its lifetime - now is not the time to start using it. and it isn't terrifically easy to set up.

Comment: Git is much better if you don't use the GUI.  If you don't have the time to delve, I don't think any of them are going to satisfy you.  Maybe Visual Source Safe would be your speed.

Comment: @Fosco No need to belittle him - the Git GUIs are pretty crappy.

Comment: http://ximbiot.com/cvs/manual/ has installation instructions, but there's a reason no one uses CVS anymore.

Comment: @Neil I wasn't intending to.. and p.s. she's a girl.

Comment: By CVS software I didn't mean specifically CVS, I am open to suggestions. As long as it satisfies the above and it's not Visual Source Safe.

Comment: @gnomiixa The generic term is VCS for "version control software" - CVS is a specific product. Both Subversion and Mercurial will do what you want.

Comment: @FOsco, I used SmartCVS and WinCVS before so I am used to using cvs, GIT however uses entirely different concept in their GUI. Their layout and interaction flow are completely different from any cvs I have ever used.

Comment: @Neil, thanks - that's what I meant. I will correct the question. Do I need to set up Mercurial server and client on my machine?

Comment: @gnomixa Subversion at http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ was specifically designed to be "a better CVS", so it will almost certainly do what you want.

Comment: @gnomixa definitely, Git is a different world entirely.  Good luck in your search.

Comment: @hnomixa No, neither Mercurial nor SVN need a server for single user use.

Comment: @Neil, can you add this an answer so i can accept it? thanks

Comment: > implying he tried one git gui and thinks that all of them are bad now.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/).

And I assume you are using Windows, so TortoiseHG is your friend
http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io

No server necessary (I am looking at you SVN/CVS), and your workspace can act as your repository.  Bazaar (http://bazaar.canonical.com/) could also work, I just happen to like Mercurial better.